# Raspbian Stretch Javafx "Cannot open Display"

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to get a GUI Javafx application running on my Raspberry Pi 3 with touchscreen. Javafx is installed using Gluon, version armv6hf-sdk. When trying to run the program using this code:

```
sudo '/usr/bin/java' -jar /home/pi/NetBeansProjects//BarSystem/dist/BarSystem.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot open display
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

It makes no difference if i try to run in remotely using NetBeans or directly on the Pi. The Pi is connected to the official 7" touchscreen and running Stretch Lite.

Java version is "1.8.0_201". I managed to get the application running on my Raspberry Pi 2 about a year ago, but are unable to achieve the same on my new pi. I already tried this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/76789/javafx-cannot-open-display-problem, but it didn't solve my problem.

I also tried to use lxterminal, but then receive a similar error:

```
(lxterminal:899): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Stretch Lite? A guess you installed JavaFX version for ARM 8 (not the new one for 11?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. I'm using Stretch Lite. JavaFX version is for ARM 8. I will edit it in the question.

Comment: I recall another question (I can't find it now) about the same issue, due probably to the lack of graphic drivers from the Lite version. Switching to the full Desktop version solved it. Probably you could try first to install those drivers (but you'll need to know which ones, of course).

Comment: I tried installing the display drivers, but there are already installed. The touchscreen is working fine as well.

Comment: There are many possible missing drivers from Lite to Desktop... Did you try the ones listed [here](https://docs.gluonhq.com/embedded/) (section 1)?